# Get users who renew the package after expiry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which gives information about which users bought a package, when it started, expired etc.

table:

```
+------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+
| user | Package_Type |   Start    |    End     | Status  |
+------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+
|  111 | A            | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-18 | Valid   |
|  123 | A            | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-18 | Valid   |
|  124 | A            | 2019-06-02 | 2019-06-06 | Expired | //Type A expired
|  124 | C            | 2019-06-02 | 2019-06-18 | Valid   |
|  125 | B            | 2019-06-03 | 2019-06-09 | Expired |
|  126 | B            | 2019-06-04 | 2019-06-20 | Valid   |
|  127 | B            | 2019-06-04 | 2019-06-07 | Expired |  // Type B expired
|  124 | B            | 2019-06-06 | 2019-06-18 | Valid   |  //Renewal to type B after expiry of type A
|  127 | B            | 2019-06-08 | 2019-06-18 | Valid   |  // Renwal to Type B
+------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+
```

In a time frame *(let timeframe be `WHERE start BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-10'`)* I wanted to know how many users whose package expired have renewed it.

Expected output is as follows

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|    Date    | Expired | Renewed |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 2019-06-01 |       0 |       0 |
| 2019-06-02 |       0 |       0 |
| 2019-06-03 |       0 |       0 |
| 2019-06-04 |       0 |       0 |
| 2019-06-05 |       0 |       0 |
| 2019-06-06 |       1 |       1 | // Expiry and renewal of user 124
| 2019-06-07 |       1 |       0 | // Expiry of user 127
| 2019-06-08 |       0 |       1 |//  Renewal of user 127
| 2019-06-09 |       1 |       0 |// Expiry of user 125
| 2019-06-10 |       0 |       0 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

It is not necessary that user has to renew to same kind of package.

1. For user 124 Type A expired but he renewed to Type B. (Also note that user 124 is still active for type C).
2. So there can be cases where a type of package expires, but same user can be active on some other package and he can renew to some different package itself.
3. I just want to know after expiry of package when the user renews.(Even if he is active on any other package)

**Update 1**
I also wanted above data to be represented as

```
+--------------+---------+---------+
| Package_Type | Expired | Renewed |
+--------------+---------+---------+
| A            |       1 |       0 |
| B            |       2 |       2 |
| C            |       0 |       0 |
+--------------+---------+---------+
```

I wanted a query in which if I change 
`WHERE start BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-10'`)*

The above table will be updated according to `start` filter

[SQL Server Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1e8d/1)

Comment: Why are you using numbers as dates in the SQL Fiddle?  These should be stored using internal date/time formats.

Comment: My bad. I pasted those values from excel as csv. I will update the fiddle. On it

Comment: Updated [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1e8d/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cumulative `max()` to get the users who have renewed:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when max(case when status = 'expired' then [start] end) over (partition by user order by [start]) < [start] and
                  status = 'Valid'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as renewed
from table1 t1;
```

You can then use this information to summarize the data.  However, this summarization is rather tricky.  The renews are counted on the start date but the expires are on the expire date.  To handle this, it unpivots the data using `apply`.

```
select dte, sum(is_expire), sum(is_renew)
from (select t1.*,
             (case when max(case when status = 'expired' then [start] end) over (partition by user order by [start]) < start and
                        status = 'Valid'
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as renewed
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 cross apply
     (values (start, 0, renewed),
             ([end], case when status = 'expired' then 1 else 0 end, 0)
     ) v(dte, is_expire, is_renew)
group by dte
order by dte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1e8d/6) is a SQLFiddle.

Comment: Fiddle shows slight variation from expected output. On date `2019-06-07` it shows `sum(is_renew)` as 1 but no renewal has happen. Only expiry of user 127 has occured

Comment: Similary on `2019-06-08` renewal of user 127 occurs.But sum(is_expire) is shown as 1 and renew is 0